Editing a bst file for an incollection (book chapter) reference style, error in order
I am editing a bst file and I need to produce the following reference of a book chapter:
Surname, IN (Year). 'Title of chapter', in Editor Surname, IN (ed.), Name of Book, Place:Publisher, pp. 1-10.
However, I'm getting this:
Surname, IN (Year). in Editor Surname, IN (ed.), Name of Book,'Title of chapter' Place:Publisher, pp. 1-10.
My problem is that I need to move the chapter title after the year.
I'm attaching the bib and the bst file.
@incollection{name,
title = {Title of chapter},
booktitle = {Name of Book},
publisher = {Publisher},
author = {Surname, Initial Names},
editor = {Editor Surname, Initial Names},
address = {Place},
year = {Year},
pages = {1--10},}

Whole bst file:
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    date
    doi
    edition
    editor
    eid
    howpublished
    institution
    isbn
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    url
    urldate
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  skip$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {non.stop}
{ duplicate$
   "}" * add.period$
   #-1 #1 substring$ "." =
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
 
 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "eds." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "(ed.)" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "vol." }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pp." }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "p." }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chap." }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Tech. Rep." }


FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      pop$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ pop$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}


INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }


STRINGS  { bibinfo}

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  "\harvardand{}"
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f{.}.~}{vv~}{ll}{ jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {

                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  "\harvardand{}"
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
    { key field.or.null }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "," *
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
      *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.isbn}
{ isbn "isbn" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "ISBN " swap$ *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    {
      "\doi{" doi * "}" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "\enquote{" swap$ *
      "}, " *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {end.quote.title}
{ title empty$
    'skip$
    { before.all 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {end.quote.btitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    'skip$
    { editor empty$
        { before.all 'output.state := }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
 "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  "\harvardand{}"
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.full.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.full}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.full
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.full
        'author.key.full
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\harvarditem" write$
  make.full.names duplicate$ label =
    'skip$
    { "[" label * "]" * write$ }
  if$
  "{" swap$ * "}{" * write$
  year duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "????" }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label * "}{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    {
      "empty year in " cite$ * "; set to n.d." * warning$
       pop$ "????"
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label *
  before.all 'output.state :=
  " \harvardyearleft " swap$ * "\harvardyearright{}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle.edition}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
  edition empty$ 'skip$
      {" \harvardyearleft " edition space.word * bbl.edition * "\harvardyearright{}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check * *
      series "series" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { swap$ bbl.of space.word * swap$
          emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number "number" bibinfo.check }
            { output.state mid.sentence =
                { bbl.number }
                { bbl.number capitalize }
              if$
              number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
              bbl.in space.word *
              series "series" bibinfo.check *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$ 'skip$
      {" \harvardyearleft " edition space.word * bbl.edition * "\harvardyearright{}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          bbl.pages swap$
          n.dashify
        }
        {
          bbl.page swap$
        }
      if$
      tie.or.space.prefix
      "pages" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ", " *
          swap$
          n.dashify
          "pages" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.eid}
{ eid "eid" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
      {
          ", " *
      }
      if$
      swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      "(" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$ *
  eid empty$
    { format.journal.pages }
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$
          "type" bibinfo.check
        }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.prefix
      "chapter" bibinfo.check
      * *
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {bt.enquote}
{ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
  { "\enquote{" swap$ *
    "}, " *
  }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
  booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
  bt.enquote
}
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{  word.in 
   editor "editor" format.names.ed " " * 
   get.bbl.editor * ", " *
   "\textit{" * booktitle * "}" *
   
}
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    { swap$ pop$
      "t" change.case$ "type" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
  type duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ bbl.techrep }
    'skip$
  if$
  "type" bibinfo.check
  swap$ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "t" change.case$ }
    { tie.or.space.prefix * * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      pop$ word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume
      swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  address empty$ t empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      address "address" bibinfo.check *
      t empty$
        'skip$
        { address empty$
            'skip$
            { ": " * }
          if$
          t *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  new.sentence
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.edition output
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  crossref missing$
    { format.isbn output }
    'skip$
  if$
  format.doi output
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  new.sentence
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
  end.quote.btitle
  format.bvolume output
  format.publisher.address output
  format.chapter.pages output
  new.sentence
  format.doi output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}
INTEGERS { len }
FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  "" 't :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      " " * bbl.etal *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal *
            }
            { " \harvardand{} " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.label}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.authors}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.label
        'author.key.label
      if$
    }
  if$
  'short.list :=
}

FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ calc.short.authors
  short.list
  ", "
  *
  year duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "????" }
     'skip$
  if$
  *
  'label :=
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.label}
{ calc.short.authors short.list
  'label :=
}
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}"
      format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          "   "  *
          namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
            { "zzzzz" 't := }
            'skip$
          if$
          t sortify *
        }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}
FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {editor.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
  if$
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}
SORT
STRINGS { last.label next.extra }
INTEGERS { last.extra.num last.extra.num.extended last.extra.num.blank number.label }
FUNCTION {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
{ #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.label :=
  "" 'next.extra :=
  #0 'last.extra.num :=
  "a" chr.to.int$ #1 - 'last.extra.num.blank :=
  last.extra.num.blank 'last.extra.num.extended :=
  #0 'number.label :=
}
FUNCTION {forward.pass}
{ last.label label =
    { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
      last.extra.num "z" chr.to.int$ >
       { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
         last.extra.num.extended #1 + 'last.extra.num.extended :=
       }
       'skip$
      if$
      last.extra.num.extended last.extra.num.blank >
        { last.extra.num.extended int.to.chr$
          last.extra.num int.to.chr$
          * 'extra.label := }
        { last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label := }
      if$
    }
    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
      "" 'extra.label :=
      label 'last.label :=
    }
  if$
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
}
FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
{ next.extra "b" =
    { "a" 'extra.label := }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label 'next.extra :=
  extra.label
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    { "{\natexlab{" swap$ * "}}" * }
  if$
  'extra.label :=
}
EXECUTE {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
ITERATE {forward.pass}
REVERSE {reverse.pass}
FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
  calc.short.label
}
ITERATE {bib.sort.order}
SORT
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{`#1'}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\urlprefix}{Available at: }"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\spacing}{ }"
  write$ newline$
  "{\catcode`\|=0\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\@=11\catcode`\\=12" write$ newline$
  "|immediate|write|@auxout{\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\gdef\natexlab#1{#1}\fi}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
  write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
%% End of customized bst file
%%
%% End of file


Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about what you've done so far. E.g., have you created the BibTeX functions from scratch, or did you take the code in an existing bst file as the starting point for your own coding? If it's the latter, please mention which bst file you started out with.

The bst file is custome made with latex makebst command. I changed the question and copied the whole bst file.

Since you've employed the makebst utility, posting the .dbj file it created en route to the bst file might be more informative.

I ran the makebst utility as well, using both information provided by the OP as well as some educated guesses. Interestingly, the resulting incollection function is quite different from what the OP reports getting. May I suggest replacing the code for the incollection function that's currently in the bst file with the following code block?
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
      format.edition output
      format.isbn output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

Aside: It would be helpful if the OP posted the dbj file instead of the bst file, as that would make it straightforward to determine the differences in the multiple-choice answers were chosen by the OP and me. Just for reference, here's the dbj file -- newtest.dbj; I know, not exactly imaginative... -- I created. The main point about this dbj file (and the associated bst file) is that it places the chapter title where the OP says it should be, viz., immediately after the year block instead of after the booktitle block.
%% Driver file to produce newtest.bst from merlin.mbs
%% Generated with makebst, version 4.1 (2003/09/08)
%% Produced on 2024/07/24 at 13:07
%% 
\input docstrip

\preamble
----------------------------------------
***  ***

\endpreamble

\postamble
End of customized bst file
\endpostamble

\keepsilent

\askforoverwritefalse
\def\MBopts{\from{merlin.mbs}{%
%EXTERNAL FILES:
%Name of language file: \cfile=.
%No included files.
%INTERNAL LANGUAGE SUPPORT (if no external language file)
    %: (def) English
% babel,%: Babel
%--------------------
%STYLE OF CITATIONS:
%   %: (def) Numerical
  ay,%: Author-year
% alph,%: Alpha style, Jon90 or JWB90
% alph,alf-1,%: Alpha style, Jon90
% alph,alf-f,%: Alpha style, Jones90
% cite,%: Cite key
%--------------------
%HTML OUTPUT (if non author-year citations)
%   %: (def) Normal LaTeX
% html,%: Hypertext
% html,htlist,%: Hypertext list
% html,htdes,%: Hypertext with keys
%--------------------
%AUTHOR--YEAR SUPPORT SYSTEM (if author-year citations)
  nat,%: Natbib
%   %: (def) Older Natbib
% alk,%: Apalike
% har,%: Harvard
% ast,%: Astronomy
% cay,%: Chicago
% nmd,%: Named
% cn,%: Author-date
%--------------------
%HARVARD EXTENSIONS INCLUDED (if Harvard support selected)
% harnm,%: With Harvard extensions
%   %: (def) Older Harvard
%--------------------
%LANGUAGE FIELD
    %: (def) No language field
% lang,%: Add language field
%--------------------
%ANNOTATIONS:
    %: (def) No annotations
% annote,%: Annotations
%--------------------
%PRESENTATIONS:
    %: (def) Do not add presentation type
% pres,%: Add presentation, speaker not highlighted
% pres,pres-bf,%: Presentation, speaker bold face
% pres,pres-it,%: Presentaion, speaker italic
% pres,pres-sc,%: Presentaion, speaker in small caps
%--------------------
%ORDERING OF REFERENCES (if non-author/year and non-alph)
%   %: (def) Alphabetical
% seq-no,%: Citation order
% seq-yr,%: Year ordered
% seq-yrr,%: Reverse year ordered
%--------------------
%ORDERING OF REFERENCES (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) Alphabetical
% seq-lab,%: By label
% seq-labc,%: By label and cite order
% seq-key,%: By label and cite key
% seq-yr,%: Year ordered
% seq-yrr,%: Reverse year ordered
% seq-no,%: Citation order
%--------------------
%ORDER ON VON PART (if not citation order)
    %: (def) Sort on von part
% vonx,%: Sort without von part
%--------------------
%IGNORE FIRST NAMES (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) Respect first names
% xintls,%: Sort on surname only
%--------------------
%AUTHOR NAMES:
% ed-au,%: Full, surname last
  nm-revf,%: Full, surname first
% nm-init,ed-au,%: Initials + surname
% nm-rev,%: Surname + initials
% nm-rv,%: Surname + dotless initials
% nm-rvvc,%: Surname + comma + spaceless initials
% nm-rvx,%: Surname + pure initials
% nm-rvcx,%: Surname + comma + pure initials
% nm-rvv,%: Surname + spaceless initials
% nm-rev1,%: Only first name reversed, initials
% nm-revv1,%: First name reversed, with full names
%--------------------
%EDITOR NAMES IN COLLECTIONS (if author names reversed)
%   %: (def) Editor names NOT reversed
  ed-rev,%: Editor names reversed
%--------------------
%POSITION OF JUNIOR (if author names reversed)
  jnrlst,%: Junior comes last
%   %: (def) Junior between
%--------------------
%JUNIOR PART IN THE CITATION (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) No `junior' part in the citations
% jnrlab,%: `Junior' in citations
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION BETWEEN AUTHOR NAMES:
    %: (def) Author names separated by commas
% aunm-semi,%: Names separated by semi-colon
% aunm-sl,%: Names separated by slash
%--------------------
%ADJACENT REFERENCES WITH REPEATED NAMES:
    %: (def) Author/editor names always present
% nmdash,%: Repeated author/editor names replaced by dash
% nmdash,nmd-2,%: Repeated author/editor names replaced by 2 dashes
% nmdash,nmd-3,%: Repeated author/editor names replaced by 3 dashes
%--------------------
%NUMBER OF AUTHORS IN BIBLIOGRAPHY:
    %: (def) All authors
% nmlm,%: Limited authors
%--------------------
%AUTHORS IN CITATIONS:
    %: (def) One author et al
% mcite,%: Some other truncation scheme
%--------------------
%MAX AUTHORS BEFORE ET AL: (if regular cite not selected)
% mct-1,%: One et al
% mct-2,%: One, Two et al
% mct-3,%: One, Two, Three et al
% mct-4,%: One, Two, Three, Four et al
% mct-5,%: One, Two, Three, Four, Five et al
% mct-6,%: One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six et al
%--------------------
%MAX AUTHORS WITHOUT ET AL: (if regular cite not selected)
% mct-x2,%: Two authors without truncating
% mct-x3,%: Three authors
% mct-x4,%: Four authors
% mct-x5,%: Five authors
% mct-x6,%: Six authors
%--------------------
%TYPEFACE FOR AUTHORS IN LIST OF REFERENCES:
    %: (def) Normal font for author names
% nmft,nmft-sc,%: Small caps authors
% nmft,nmft-it,%: Italic authors
% nmft,nmft-bf,%: Bold authors
% nmft,nmft-def,%: User defined author font
%--------------------
%FONT FOR FIRST NAMES (if non-default font for authors)
%   %: (def) First names same font as surnames
% fnm-rm,%: First names in normal font
% fnm-def,%: First names in user defined font
%--------------------
%EDITOR NAMES IN INCOLLECTION ETC:
%   %: (def) Editors incollection normal font
% nmfted,%: Editors incollection like authors
%--------------------
%FONT FOR `AND' IN LIST:
%   %: (def) `And' in author font
% nmand-rm,%: `And' in normal font
%--------------------
%FONT OF CITATION LABELS IN TEXT (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) Cited authors plain
% lab,lab-it,%: Cited authors italic
% lab,lab-sc,%: Cited authors small caps
% lab,lab-bf,%: Cited authors bold
% lab,lab-def,%: User defined citation font
%--------------------
%FONT FOR `AND' IN CITATIONS (if non-default font for citation lables)
%   %: (def) Cited `and' in author font
% and-rm,%: Cited `and' in normal font
%--------------------
%FONT OF EXTRA LABEL (The extra letter on the year)
    %: (def) Extra label plain
% xlab-it,%: Extra label italic
%--------------------
%LABEL WHEN AUTHORS MISSING (if author-year citations)
  keyxyr,%: Year blank when KEY replaces missing author
%   %: (def) Year included when KEY replaces missing author
%--------------------
%MISSING DATE (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) Missing date set to ????
% blkyear,%: Missing date left blank
%--------------------
%DATE POSITION:
%   %: (def) Date at end
  dt-beg,%: Date after authors
% dt-jnl,%: Date part of journal spec.
% dt-end,%: Date at very end
%--------------------
%DATE FORMAT (if non author-year citations)
%   %: (def) Plain month and year
% yr-par,%: Date in parentheses
% yr-brk,%: Date in brackets
% yr-col,%: Date preceded by colon
% yr-per,%: Date preceded by period
% yr-com,%: Date preceded by comma
% yr-blk,%: Date preceded by space
%--------------------
%SUPPRESS MONTH:
%   %: (def) Date is month and year
% xmth,%: Date is year only
%--------------------
%REVERSED DATE (if including month)
%   %: (def) Date as month year
% dtrev,%: Date as year month
%--------------------
%DATE FORMAT (if author-year citations)
%   %: (def) Year plain
  yr-par,%: Year in parentheses
% yr-brk,%: Year in brackets
% yr-col,%: Year preceded by colon
% yr-per,%: Year preceded by period
% yr-com,%: Date preceded by comma
% yr-blk,%: Year preceded by space
%--------------------
%INCLUDE MONTHS:
    %: (def) Date is year only
% aymth,%: Include month in date
%--------------------
%REVERSED DATE (if including month)
%   %: (def) Date as month year
% dtrev,%: Date as year month
%--------------------
%DATE PUNCTUATION (if date not at end)
    %: (def) Date with standard block punctuation
% yrp-col,%: Colon after date
% yrp-semi,%: Semi-colon after date
% yrp-per,%: Period after date
% yrp-x,%: No punct. after date
%--------------------
%BLANK AFTER DATE:
    %: (def) Space after date
% yrpp-xsp,%: No space after date
%--------------------
%DATE FONT:
    %: (def) Date in normal font
% dtbf,%: Date in bold face
%--------------------
%TRUNCATE YEAR (if author-year citations)
  note-yr,%: Year text full
%   %: (def) Year truncated
%--------------------
%TITLE OF ARTICLE:
    %: (def) Title plain
% tit-it,%: Title italic
% tit-qq,qt-s,%: Title and punctuation in single quotes
% tit-qq,%: Title and punctuation in double quotes
% tit-qq,qt-g,%: Title and punctuation in guillemets
% tit-qq,qt-s,qx,%: Title in single quotes
% tit-qq,qx,%: Title in double quotes
% tit-qq,qt-g,qx,%: Title in guillemets
%--------------------
%COLLECTION/PROCEEDINGS TITLES (if quoted title)
% bt-qq,%: Quote collection and proceedings titles
%   %: (def) Collection and proceedings titles not in quotes
%--------------------
%CAPITALIZATION OF ARTICLE TITLE:
    %: (def) Sentence style
% atit-u,%: Title style
%--------------------
%ARTICLE TITLE PRESENT:
    %: (def) Article title present
% jtit-x,%: No article title
%--------------------
%JOURNAL NAMES:
    %: (def) Periods in journal names
% jxper,%: Dotless journal names
%--------------------
%JOURNAL NAME FONT:
    %: (def) Journal name italics
% jttl-rm,%: Journal name normal
%--------------------
%THESIS TITLE:
    %: (def) Thesis titles like books
% thtit-a,%: Thesis title like article
% thtit-x,%: No thesis title
%--------------------
%TECHNICAL REPORT TITLE:
    %: (def) Tech. report title like articles
% trtit-b,%: Tech. report title like books
%--------------------
%TECHNICAL REPORT NUMBER:
    %: (def) Tech. report and number plain
% trnum-it,%: Tech. report and number italic
%--------------------
%JOURNAL VOLUME:
    %: (def) Volume plain
% vol-it,%: Volume italic
% vol-bf,%: Volume bold
% vol-2bf,%: Volume and number bold
%--------------------
%JOURNAL VOL AND NUMBER:
    %: (def) Journal vol(num)
% vnum-sp,%: Journal vol (num)
% vnum-cm,%: Journal vol, num
% vnum-nr,%: Journal vol, no. num
% vnum-h,%: Journal vol, \# number
% vnum-b,%: Journal vol number
% vnum-x,%: Journal vol, without number
%--------------------
%VOLUME PUNCTUATION:
    %: (def) Volume with colon
% volp-sp,%: Volume with colon and space
% volp-semi,%: Volume with semi-colon
% volp-com,%: Volume with comma
% volp-blk,%: Volume with blank
%--------------------
%YEAR IN JOURNAL SPECIFICATION:
    %: (def) Journal year like others
% jdt-v,%: Journal vol(year)
% jdt-vs,%: Journal vol (year)
% jdt-p,%: Year with pages
% jdt-pc,%: Year, comma, pages
%--------------------
%PAGE NUMBERS:
    %: (def) Start and stop page numbers
% jpg-1,%: Only start page number
%--------------------
%LARGE PAGE NUMBERS:
    %: (def) No separators for large page numbers
% pgsep-c,%: Comma inserted over 9999
% pgsep-s,%: Thin space inserted over 9999
% pgsep-p,%: Period inserted over 9999
%--------------------
%WORD `PAGE' IN ARTICLES:
    %: (def) Article pages numbers only
% jwdpg,%: Include `page' in articles
%--------------------
%POSITION OF PAGES:
%   %: (def) Pages given mid text
  pp-last,%: Pages at end
%--------------------
%WORD `VOLUME' IN ARTICLES:
    %: (def) Article volume as number only
% jwdvol,%: Include `volume' in articles
%--------------------
%NUMBER AND SERIES FOR COLLECTIONS:
  num-xser,%: Allows number without series
%   %: (def) Standard BibTeX
%--------------------
%POSITION OF NUMBER AND SERIES:
    %: (def) After chapter and pages
% numser,%: Just before publisher
%--------------------
%VOLUME AND SERIES FOR BOOKS/COLLECTIONS:
    %: (def) Vol. 23 of Series
% ser-vol,%: Series, vol. 23
%--------------------
%POSITION OF VOLUME AND SERIES FOR INCOLLECTIONS:
    %: (def) Series and volume after the editors
% ser-ed,%: Series and volume after booktitle
%--------------------
%JOURNAL NAME PUNCTUATION:
    %: (def) Comma after journal
% jnm-x,%: Space after journal
%--------------------
%BOOK TITLE:
    %: (def) Book title italic
% btit-rm,bt-rm,%: Book title plain
%--------------------
%PAGES IN BOOKS:
    %: (def) Pages in book plain
% bkpg-par,%: Pages in book in parentheses
% bkpg-x,%: Pages in book bare
%--------------------
%TOTAL PAGES OF A BOOK:
    %: (def) Total book pages not printed
% pg-bk,%: For book: 345 pages
% pg-bk,pg-pre,%: Total book pages before publisher
%--------------------
%PUBLISHER ADDRESS:
%   %: (def) Publisher, address
  add-pub,%: Address: Publisher
%--------------------
%PUBLISHER IN PARENTHESES:
    %: (def) Publisher as normal block
% pub-par,%: Publisher in parentheses
% pub-date,%: Publisher and date in parentheses
% pub-date,pub-xc,%: Publisher and date in parentheses, no comma
% pub-date,pub-xpar,%: Publisher and date without parentheses
% pub-date,pub-xpar,pub-xc,%: Publisher and date, no parentheses, no comma
%--------------------
%PUBLISHER POSITION:
    %: (def) Publisher after chapter, pages
% pre-pub,%: Publisher before chapter, pages
% pre-edn,%: Publisher after edition
%--------------------
%ISBN NUMBER:
  isbn,%: Include ISBN
%   %: (def) No ISBN
%--------------------
%ISSN NUMBER:
  issn,%: Include ISSN
%   %: (def) No ISSN
%--------------------
%DOI NUMBER:
  doi,%: Include DOI
% url-doi,%: Format DOI as URL //dx.doi.org/doi
% agu-doi,doi,%: Insert DOI AGU style
%   %: (def) No DOI
%--------------------
%`EDITOR' AFTER NAMES (EDITED BOOKS WITHOUT AUTHORS):
%   %: (def) Word `editor' after name
  edpar,%: `Name (editor),'
% edpar,bkedcap,%: `Name (Editor),'
% edparc,%: `Name, (editor)'
% edparc,bkedcap,%: `Name, (Editor)'
% edparxc,%: `Name (editor)'
% edparxc,bkedcap,%: `Name (Editor)'
%--------------------
%EDITOR IN COLLECTIONS:
    %: (def) Same as for edited book
% edby,%: In booktitle, edited by .. 
% edby-par,%: In booktitle (edited by ..)
% edby-parc,%: In booktitle, (edited by ..)
% edby,edbyx,%: In booktitle, editor ..
% edby,edbyw,%: In booktitle, (editor) ..
% edby-par,edbyx,%: In booktitle (editor..)
% edby-parc,edbyx,%: In booktitle, (editor..)
% edby,edbyy,%: In booktitle, .., editor
% edby-par,edbyy,%: In booktitle (.., editor)
%--------------------
%CAPITALIZE `EDITOR' OR `EDITED BY' (if editor capitalizable)
%   %: (def) `(editor,..)' or `(edited by..)'
% edcap,%: `(Editor,..)' or `(Edited by..)'
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION BETWEEN SECTIONS (BLOCKS):
    %: (def) \newblock after blocks
% blk-com,%: Comma between blocks
% blk-com,com-semi,%: Semi-colon between blocks
% blk-com,com-blank,%: Blanks between blocks
% blk-tit,%: Period after titles of articles, books, etc
% blk-tit,tit-col,%: Colon after titles of articles, books, etc
% blk-tita,%: Period after titles of articles
% blk-tita,tit-col,%: Colon after titles of articles
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION BEFORE NOTES (if not using \newblock)
%   %: (def) Notes have regular punctuation
% blknt,%: Notes preceded by period
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION AFTER AUTHORS:
    %: (def) Author block normal
% au-col,%: Author block with colon
%--------------------
%PUNCTUATION AFTER `IN':
    %: (def) Space after `in'
% in-col,%: Colon after `in'
% in-it,%: Italic `in'
% in-col,in-it,%: Italic `in' and colon
% in-x,%: No word `in'
%--------------------
%`IN' WITH JOURNAL NAMES (if using 'in' with collections)
    %: (def) No `in' before journal name
% injnl,%: Add `in' before journal name
%--------------------
%FINAL PUNCTUATION:
    %: (def) Period at very end
% fin-bare,%: No period at end
%--------------------
%ABBREVIATE WORD `PAGES' (if not using external language file)
    %: (def) `Page(s)'
% pp,%: `Page' abbreviated
% ppx,%: `Page' omitted
%--------------------
%ABBREVIATE WORD `EDITORS':
%   %: (def) `Editor(s)'
  ed,%: `Editor' abbreviated
%--------------------
%OTHER ABBREVIATIONS:
    %: (def) No abbreviations
% abr,%: Abbreviations
%--------------------
%ABBREVIATION FOR `EDITION' (if abbreviating words)
%   %: (def) `Edition' abbreviated as `edn'
% ednx,%: `Edition' abbreviated as `ed'
%--------------------
%MONTHS WITH DOTS:
%   %: (def) Months with dots
% mth-bare,%: Months without dots
%--------------------
%EDITION NUMBERS:
  xedn,%: Editions as in database
%   %: (def) Write out editions
% ord,%: Numerical editions
%--------------------
%Reading external language file \cfile=
%STORED JOURNAL NAMES:
    %: (def) Full journal names
% jabr,%: Abbreviated journal names
% jabr,jaa,%: Abbreviated with astronomy shorthands
%--------------------
%AMPERSAND:
    %: (def) Use word `and'
% amper,%: Use ampersand
% varand,%: Use \BIBand
%--------------------
%COMMA BEFORE `AND':
    %: (def) Comma before `and'
% and-xcom,%: No comma before `and'
% and-com,%: Comma even with 2 authors
%--------------------
%COMMA BEFORE `AND' EVEN FOR COLLECTION EDITORS (if using comma before `and' with authors)
% and-com-ed,%: Comma with 2 editors
%   %: (def) Two editors without comma
%--------------------
%NO `AND' IN REFERENCE LIST:
    %: (def) With `and'
% xand,%: No `and'
%--------------------
%COMMA BEFORE `ET AL':
    %: (def) Comma before `et al'
% etal-xc,%: No comma before `et al'
%--------------------
%FONT OF `ET AL':
    %: (def) Plain et al
% etal-it,%: Italic et al
% etal-rm,%: Roman et al
%--------------------
%ADDITIONAL REVTeX DATA FIELDS:
    %: (def) No additional fields
% revdata,eprint,url,url-blk,%: Include REVTeX data fields
%--------------------
%E-PRINT DATA FIELD: (without REVTeX fields)
    %: (def) Do not include eprint field
% eprint,%: Include eprint and archive fields
%--------------------
%URL ADDRESS: (without REVTeX fields)
    %: (def) No URL
% url,url-blk,%: Include URL
% url,url-nt,%: URL as note
% url,url-nl,%: URL on new line
%--------------------
%REFERENCE COMPONENT TAGS:
    %: (def) No reference component tags
% bibinfo,%: Reference component tags
%--------------------
%EMPHASIS: (affects all so-called italics)
    %: (def) Use emphasis
% em-it,%: Use true italics
% em-x,%: No italics
% em-ul,%: Underlining
%--------------------
%COMPATIBILITY WITH PLAIN TEX:
  nfss,%: Use LaTeX commands
% plntx,%: Use only Plain TeX
%--------------------
  }}
\generate{\file{newtest.bst}{\MBopts}}
\endbatchfile

